# Gstreamer on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gstreamer

I want to create an app to remote controle an RC car I have built, the last thing I have to add is to display a livestream of the car's camera in the background of my onscreen controls. At the moment I have a little app for each feature, which I want to assemble to a big application with all features. My problem is that I can't compile my gstreamer dummy app, because it says that the compiler would miss a header file. An other problem is that I don't know how to create a video sink in a qml app with a c++ backend.
It would be very nice if someone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Noone knows an answer? Is there a way to ask it again?